# Fully understanding the BufferStrategy code sample from Java docs

Tags: java, awt, graphics2d

The [official java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferStrategy.html) gives an example on how to use the BufferStrategy:

```
// Render single frame
 do {
     // The following loop ensures that the contents of the drawing buffer
     // are consistent in case the underlying surface was recreated
     do {
         // Get a new graphics context every time through the loop
         // to make sure the strategy is validated
         Graphics graphics = strategy.getDrawGraphics();

         // Render to graphics
         // ...

         // Dispose the graphics
         graphics.dispose();

         // Repeat the rendering if the drawing buffer contents
         // were restored
     } while (strategy.contentsRestored());

     // Display the buffer
     strategy.show();

     // Repeat the rendering if the drawing buffer was lost
 } while (strategy.contentsLost());
```

However, I was not able to fully grasp whats going on here as the documentation is quiet sparse with samples.

From this code sample I got the following notion: While invoking several methods on the graphics object, the underlying video memory (VRAM) might get lost and restored halfway through. The whole rendering process has to be repeated. What I do not get, is why there is a check for contents lost after show has been invoked on the strategy instance?